# UIPickerView How to fill rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

i am trying to fill the rows of my uipickerview with content and i'm trying to do it like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString *test;

for (int i; i<5; i++) {
        if (row == i) {
            test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
            return test;
        }


}

return @"";
```

}

But it doesn't display all of the numbers and sometimes they even disappear....
What am i doing wrong? i don't want to have to fill all of the rows manually because i am going to fill this pickerview with minutes and seconds which would make this a view with 60 rows.....
Any help is greatly appreceated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the string you want to appear in a row:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                                         forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

UIPicker will call this delegate method only when the row is about to display.

P.S. Have a look at `UIDatePicker` - may be it already does what you want

Comment: Unfortunately the UIDatePicker can only display hours and minutes instead of seconds and minutes and i wouldn't know how to change that..